# having android downloadable themes in an application

Tags: android, themes, styles

In the android application that we are building, we would like to have a feature that enables a user to download a theme and apply it to the application.

Currently, in android, one has to define the themes and ship them along with the apk file.
Is there a way to say, store them on a web server, allow the user to download them, and then apply them to the application? If yes, then how?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, currently there is no way to dynamically load themes. Only statically defined themes can be used.

Comment: But then how do aHome and pandaHome applications do it?

Comment: They could've implement their own theme layer.